# Where can I search for artifact version dependencies for jira java rest APIs?

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, jira-rest-api

I am newbie to maven/jira rest APIs. I have a very basic need of searching/finding the right version for the dependencies in my pom.xml, but I am not aware of any such maven repo site to look for. Please help..

Comment: I am not sure if this will help https://maven.atlassian.com/public/com/atlassian/jira/jira-rest-java-client/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the repositories needed, if working with Java and Maven:

https://maven.atlassian.com/content/groups/public/

http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

Please note that Jira Rest client requires many dependencies like Jersey, Guava, Jettison etc.

Hope this helps!